# DocuSign Service Integration live account can't authenticate

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I've built a DocuSign integration that works fine with a sandbox account, but I'm having trouble with a live account. I'm using the [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client). I'm using an authorization code grant with impersonation. Debugging shows that a `LoginInformation` object is created, but it's LoginAccounts property is null, which, of course, breaks the code attempting to get the appropriate base URL for subsequent API calls. Any suggestions?

```
public static ApiClient GetDocuSignClient()
{
    string accountType = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName + ".DocuSignAccountType");
    string integratorKey = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName + ".DocuSignIntegratorKey");
    string userID = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName + ".DocuSignUserID");
    string rsaPrivate = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName + ".DocuSignRSAKey");
    string basePath = accountType == "sandbox" ? "account-d.docusign.com" : "account.docusign.com";
    // this gets replaced when we communicate with the api
    string clientBasePath = accountType == "sandbox" ? "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi" : "https://www.docusign.net/restapi";
    int expirationHours = 1;

    if (accountType == "" || integratorKey == "" || userID == "" || rsaPrivate == "")
        throw new System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException("All DocuSign settings must be set in Settings->Integration->DocuSign");

    ApiClient dsClient = new ApiClient(clientBasePath);
    dsClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow(integratorKey, userID, basePath, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rsaPrivate), expirationHours);


    AuthenticationApi authClient = new AuthenticationApi(dsClient.Configuration);
    LoginInformation loginInfo = authClient.Login();

    // find the default account for this user
    foreach (LoginAccount loginAcct in loginInfo.LoginAccounts)
    {
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what are either errors or very misleading statements in the DocuSign API documentation. It seems the oauth/userinfo call returns the base URL for an account in different formats for sandbox and live accounts. The following code is a bit messy, but it's working for both.

```
public static ApiClient GetDocuSignClient()
{
    string accountType = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName + ".DocuSignAccountType");
    string integratorKey = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName + ".DocuSignIntegratorKey");
    string userID = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName + ".DocuSignUserID");
    string rsaPrivate = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName + ".DocuSignRSAKey");
    string basePath = accountType == "sandbox" ? "account-d.docusign.com" : "account.docusign.com";
    // this gets replaced when we communicate with the api
    string clientBasePath = accountType == "sandbox" ? "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi" : "https://www.docusign.net/restapi";
    int expirationHours = 1;

    if (accountType == "" || integratorKey == "" || userID == "" || rsaPrivate == "")
        throw new System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException("All DocuSign settings must be set in Settings->Integration->DocuSign");

    ApiClient dsClient = new ApiClient(clientBasePath);
    dsClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow(integratorKey, userID, basePath, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rsaPrivate), expirationHours);

    var rsUserClient = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://" + basePath); ;
    RestSharp.RestRequest acctReq = new RestSharp.RestRequest();
    acctReq.Method = RestSharp.Method.GET;
    acctReq.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
    acctReq.Resource = "oauth/userinfo";

    // even though we're not using the SDK to get accounts, we can use the token it generates
    AuthenticationApi authClient = new AuthenticationApi(dsClient.Configuration);
    acctReq.AddHeader("Authorization", authClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader["Authorization"]);


    RestSharp.IRestResponse rsResponse = rsUserClient.Execute(acctReq);
    if (rsResponse.ResponseStatus != RestSharp.ResponseStatus.Completed || rsResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        if (rsResponse.ErrorException != null)
            throw new WebException("DocuSign login failed: " + rsResponse.ErrorException.Message, rsResponse.ErrorException);
        else if (rsResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            throw new WebException(String.Format("DocuSign login failed. StatusCode: {0} <br/>ErrorDescription: {1}", rsResponse.StatusCode, rsResponse.Content));
        else
            throw new WebException(String.Format("DocuSign login failed. StatusCode: {0} ResponseStatus: {1}", rsResponse.StatusCode, rsResponse.ResponseStatus));
    }

    DocuSignLoginInfo loginInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocuSignLoginInfo>(rsResponse.Content);
    DocuSignLoginAccount toUse = null;
    foreach (var loginAcct in loginInfo.Accounts)
    {
        if (toUse == null)
        {
            toUse = loginAcct; // use first account
        }
        else if (loginAcct.IsDefault && 
            ((accountType == "sandbox" && loginAcct.Base_Uri.Contains("demo.")) || 
            (accountType != "sandbox" && !loginAcct.Base_Uri.Contains("demo."))))
        {
            toUse = loginAcct; // use default account if appropriate
        }

    }

    if (toUse == null)
    {
        throw new WebException("DocuSign login failed: " + loginInfo.Email + " doesn't have a login account we can use.");
    }
    else
    {
        SettingsKeyInfoProvider.SetValue("DocuSignAccountID", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, toUse.Account_Id);

        string[] separatingStrings = { "/v2" };

        string restUrl = toUse.Base_Uri.Split(separatingStrings, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
        if (!restUrl.Contains("/restapi"))
            restUrl += "/restapi";

        // Update ApiClient with the new base url from login call
        dsClient = new ApiClient(restUrl);
    }


    return dsClient;
}

public class DocuSignLoginAccount
{
    public string Account_Id;
    public string Account_Name;
    public bool IsDefault;
    public string Base_Uri;
}

public class EnvelopeBrief
{
    public string EnvID;
    public Signer CurrentSigner;
    public string ClientUserID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per our [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/login/) also, With OAUTH (and JWT), you should not use Login_information API, instead you need to use [User Info](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/userinfo.html) API Call to get the base URI. Once you get the Base URI then you all other non-authentication related APIs using this Base URI. Demo environment is only at one data center, so with your current code it is working fine in Sandbox, but PROD has multiple data centers like NA1, NA2, NA3, EU1, and your account can be in any one of them, so to know the exact URI to use to hit data center for creating envelopes, you need to use [User Info](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/userinfo.html) API call to know the Base URI.

Currently in your code, you have hard coded the BaseUri (or client Base Path) `clientBasePath = https://www.docusign.net/restapi`, in this hard coding you are assuming that your PROD account is in NA1, but as I mentioned earlier it can be in any other datacenters also, so please change the code to call userinfo/ API call. Our SDK has this code (of incorrectly calling LoginInformation instead of userinfo/) incorrectly written and I have already reported it to DS Dev center team to fix this flow.